# How to assign a text as input field value

Tags: jquery, input

In the following code, I intended to target the input field by its ID, grab the text of an h4 an make it as the value of the input field.

```
$('input#nf-field-22').change(function() {
    var produc_name = $('h4.single_title').text();
    $(this).val($produc_name);
});
```

So far it does not work.

Comment: Check your browser console (next time before asking, thank you) - it will tell you that `$produc_name` does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Change `$produc_name` to `produc_name`:

```
$('input#nf-field-22').change(function() {
        var produc_name = $('h4.single_title').text();
        $(this).val(produc_name);
});
```